# How to allow protractor test to register custom protocol handler in chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

When I register a custom protocol handler by executing script with `browser.executeScript(navigator.registerProtocolHandler(protocol, url, title));` a little icon appears in the address bar that has to be clicked and I have to choose option "allow" (ignore is by default);
but how to do that with protractor ?
I know that chrome options can be set through `chromeOptions` object in conf file

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['']
  }
}
```

but which option from this list is suitable for my problem
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

or maybe there is other solution?

Comment: There is `--disable-custom-protocol-os-check` which I found here: http://www.mobitechie.com/browser/chrome-chromium-command-line-switches/ possible that it is deprecated, but worth a shot.

Comment: 10x mate but it doesn't work , i am wondering if i can add something in executeScript function so it automatically allows registering the new handler

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out; try this:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName' : 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions' : {
        args: [],
        prefs : {
            custom_handlers : {
                'enabled' : true,
                'registered_protocol_handlers' : [
                    {
                        'default' : true,
                        'protocol' : '',
                        'title' : '',
                        'url' : ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously fill in the protocol, url and title as applicable.

Comment: 10x mate that's it !